# Bottom navigation not working in android?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I have create a custom bottom navigation menu like below

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/ic_camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_camera"
        android:title="">
    </item>
```

I have include that in my main activity and I have use a frame layout to go create fragments when i click item it will change

`activity_main.xml` file like below

```
       <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="53dp">

        </FrameLayout>

        <!--bottom navigartion-->
        <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view" />
```

my `MainActivity.java` file like below what did I do wrong

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_view_bar);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottmNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

        BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener
                = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.ic_home :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_search :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new SearchFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_camera :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new CameraFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_alert :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new AlertFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.ic_user :
                        transaction.replace(R.id.container, new UserFragment()).commit();
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: `Bottom navigation not working` can you explain more.?

Comment: Im try to navigate throw fragments using menu items in bottom navigationbar above code is what i have done but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include layout_bottom_navigation_view  inside the  frame layout or another way is set fragmelayout margin bottom  is height of layout_bottom_navigation_view

```
  <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp">
      <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation_view" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Edited : bottomNavigationViewEx use instead of BottomNavigationViewEx then onclick will be work

```
 bottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener onNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
   }
```

Comment: its not going to onitem click i have put toast for clicks but not showing

Comment: bottomNavigationViewEx use instead of BottomNavigationViewEx ...check edited answer